# Tex file run error

Tags: formatting, format-files

When I run the tex file by Winedit, the out put shows like this.
How to check this error?[image]

How to find the wrong in the tex file?

Comment: This is not the part of the error message from which we can say where is the error.. It is before that

Comment: Most likely, you forgot to close a mathematical environment. You should check your code carefully, since it might be hard to automagically isolate the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The `*` prompt means that TeX has run off the end of the file, despite the fact it says to type `\end` it is better to type `\stop`  or just `\anyoldrubbish` to get an error then type `x` to stop at the `?` prompt.

The most direct reason for getting that is to forget `\end{document}` although sometimes you have an `\end{document}` but an earlier error prevents it being seen for some reason.

Your first error was a math `$` missing, it is better to stop at that `?` prompt with `x` and correct that first.